# Chrome popup on random urls?

Tags: google-chrome

I have a NAS on a local IP address, 192.168.x.x.
When I open Chrome and go to that address, I'm seeing a suppressed popup. If I permit the popup, it goes to Uniregistry (a Go-daddy co). FWIW, this doesn't happen in Firefox. Trying to understand why this occurs.
I am running Yosemite 10.10.5 on a 2010 MacPro.

Update - I was going down the wrong path. This is unrelated to the NAS/local IP issue.

[image]

The same redirect was blocked when visiting a math blog.
Aside from confirming that Chrome is set to block redirects, I'm still trying to understand their source.

Comment: I’m not seeing where this is an Apple issue since it’s the NAS that’s creating the website/page that's got the popup.  Everything you’ve described shows everything working as expected.  It’s also not not clear what exactly you’re “trying to understand” - the NAS, the popup, GoDaddy relation, browser behavior, etc.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as written this question is not about Apple hardware, software, or services as described in the [help]

Comment: It’s a local device. Trying to understand why chrome creates a pop up, but Firefox doesn’t.    But I do understand this will be closed as not Mac relevant.

Comment: To point you in the right direction, take a look at the configurations of both FF and Chrome.  They handle popups differently (internally).

Comment: What are your proxy settings on both Chrome and FF?  It's still confusing though.  You say when you go to a local IP 192.168.x.x you get a popup in Chrome.  but later, you say "this is unrelated to NAS/Local IP"  Can you clarify as to what sites are triggering the popup?  Is it local or not?

Comment: I added that, as an update. This was the first I ever noticed the redirect attempt, when looking to see the NAS. But, today, I clicked over to the blog I referenced, and see the same redirect attempt. I am still troubleshooting.

Comment: Chrome proxy setting just refer me to those on my Mac, where I have no proxy set up.

Comment: You might also want to run [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/)

Comment: (Done! and see below. Case closed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a bit of the scientific method, narrowing down the cause of the popup.

Other browsers didn't have the same issue, only Chrome. And the popup was occuring on my own NAS, with no other users reporting such an infection.

So, back to Chrome. I looked at my extensions. Over 2 dozen. Turned them all off, and the popups stopped. Turned them on, 4 at a time, until I found the one that caused this. When I clicked to look in the Chrome store, it's no longer listed. Mystery solved.
(Thank you, Allan, for the time and patience, and the SW reference, which helped me find unwelcome adware.)